# Want to store json data from file to sqlite database but getting error

Tags: node.js, json, sqlite

**Error**

> { db.transaction(function(tx){ TypeError: db.transaction is not a
>   function }

I am setting up a question bank backup in my SQLite database so I have question bank in JSON file form. I have written the following code but couldn't get the error as I just started coding with nodejs.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('json.sqlite3');
var file = process.env.CLOUD_DIR + "json.sqlite3";
var exists = fs.existsSync(file);
var jsonfile = {
key: "myvalue"
};

fs.readFile('demo.json', function (err, data) {
if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
}
console.log("File content: " + data.toString());
// now save to db


if(!exists) {
console.log("Creating DB file.");
fs.openSync(file, "w");
}


db.serialize(function() {
if(!exists) {
db.run("CREATE TABLE Stuff (thing TEXT)");
 }


var jsonString = escape(JSON.stringify(data.toString()));

    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Stuff(md5, json,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

 expires) VALUES ("'+hash+'", "'+jsonString+'","'+expireStamp+'")');
    },function(tx,error){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tx.message));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    },function(){

        });
    });
  });
  db.close();
```

JSON should be easily updated, edited, and retrieved from the SQLite Database

Answer (score 1):

The error message `db.transaction(function(tx){ TypeError: db.transaction is not a function`  is clear and unambiguous.

Review the [API doc](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API) for a list of available methods on a Database object.

I have found [this tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/) very helpful during the learning process.